# Printing out an array in twig using a for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, twig

i have to configurate a .csv file.
I have a variable that is either a single value or an array of values. If it is a single value, i want to put that single value into the cell, otherwise i want to put every value in the array into the cell.

This is my approach, but it's not iterating through the array. If the item is an array, it just puts nothing into to table cell. Do i need to increment i in some sort of way?

```
{% if item is iterable %}

{% for i in item[0..10]%}
     *{{ item[i] }}
{% endfor %}

{% else %}
{{item}}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why are you using `{% for i in item[0..10]%}` to iterate the item?
`0..10` returns an array in twig, which will result in the following "code"

```html
{% for i in item[Array] %}
```

This will return nothing as the index `Array` doesn't exist in the array `item`.
The proper way to iterate the value would be

```html
{% if item is iterable %}
    {% for i in item %}
        {{ i }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{item}}
{% endif %}
```

---

If you are trying to display only 10 values from the array u'd go with

```html
{% for i in item[0:10]%}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```html
{% for i in item|slice(0, 10) %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```